# Extracting information from an HTML parsed document

Tags: r

I'm new to HTML and XML processing, and have a question about extracting certain parts of a parsed HTML document. The following document `doc`, was produced with `htmlTreeParse` in package `XML`, and can be reproduced with the following code.

**What happens to the four-digit number at the end of each line when** `href="..."` **is accessed?**  I need to extract those numbers, but they seem to disappear.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/index",
                     useInternalNodes = TRUE)
doc["//a/@href"][100:101]
# [[1]]
#                                            href 
# "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl1924.zip" 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLAttributeValue"
# 
# [[2]]
#                                            href 
# "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl1925.zip" 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "XMLAttributeValue"
```

So basically, from the following I want to extract the final four digits.  The result should be the vector

```
[1] 1871 1872 ... ... 2012 2013
```

Here's a peek at the html document

```
...
  <br/>
    </b>
    <pre>
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl1871.zip">1871</a>
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl1872.zip">1872</a>
    ...                                                     ....
    ...                                                     ....
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl2012.zip">2012</a>
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/gl2013.zip">2013</a>
    </pre>
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glws.zip">World Series</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glas.zip">All-Star</a>
    <br/>
```

Comment: Try `doc["//a/text()"][100:101]` or `sapply(doc["//a"][100:101], xmlValue)` or `sapply(doc["//a"][100:101], xmlValue, trim = TRUE)` if you want the value instead of the href attribute.

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I thought. Thanks a lot.  Glad I didn't go `grep` on it.  Will you submit that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value instead of the href attribute, try one of the following:

```
doc["//a/text()"][100:101] 
sapply(doc["//a"][100:101], xmlValue) 
sapply(doc["//a"][100:101], xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```